# Custom control doesn't display in window

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uiwindow

I'v created view based application. And Added new class which extends from UIView. This class contains some controls in it (simple controls). Now I want to display/hide this control when user click on something. Control should be displayed as a overlay window. Over all other controls. I try to do this like:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];        
    addSubview:myOverlayChannelPicker;
}
```

Everything goes fine, debug get in custom control code but nothing display on screen. I tried to add it manually and it works, but I need to add it in runtime. What could be the reason for not displaying control?

Complete code for OverlayChannelPicker

```
@implementation OverlayChannelPicker
@synthesize myImage;
@synthesize img1;
@synthesize img2;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frame])) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib{
    img1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imgTest.jpg"];
    img2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imgTest2.jpg"];

    arrayOfImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [arrayOfImages addObject:img1];
    [arrayOfImages addObject:img2];
    [arrayOfImages addObject:img1];
    [arrayOfImages addObject:img2];
    [arrayOfImages addObject:img1];
    [arrayOfImages addObject:img2];
    [arrayOfImages addObject:img1];
    [arrayOfImages addObject:img2];
    [arrayOfImages addObject:img1];
    [arrayOfImages addObject:img2];
    [arrayOfImages addObject:img1];
    [arrayOfImages addObject:img2];

    scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] init];
    scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    scrollView.pagingEnabled = NO; // for smooth scroll
    scrollView.directionalLockEnabled = YES;
    scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
    scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    scrollView.delegate = self;
    //scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    scrollView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
    scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 150, 320, 128);
    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(1620, 128)];
    [self addSubview:scrollView];

    UIImage *imageToAdd;
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    for(imageToAdd in arrayOfImages)
    {       
        UIImageView *temp = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:imageToAdd];     

        temp.frame = CGRectMake(x, y, 128, 128);
        temp.userInteractionEnabled = YES;      
        x += 135;


        UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imageTapped:)];
        [temp addGestureRecognizer:tap];    

        [scrollView addSubview:temp];
    }

}

- (void)imageTapped:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender
{       
    UIImageView *iv = (UIImageView *)[sender view];
    UIImage *image = [iv image];
    UIImage *it = [arrayOfImages indexOfObject:image];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:iv cache:YES];

    if(it == img1)
        it = img2;
    else
        it = img1;

    [UIView commitAnimations];  
}
```

And it's header:

```
@interface OverlayChannelPicker : UIView <UIScrollViewDelegate>{
    IBOutlet UIImageView *myImage;
    UIImage *img1;
    UIImage *img2;  

    IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
    int view1Index;
    int view2Index; 
    NSMutableArray *arrayOfImages;

}
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *myImage;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *img1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *img2;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIScrollView *scrollView;

- (void)awakeFromNib;
@end
```

Comment: But how do you create `myOverlayChannelPicker`? Have you verified that it is not nil?

Comment: I added to header: OverlayChannelPicker *myOverlayChannelPicker; and added property/synthesize for it. And then call [self.view addSub...];

Comment: I added this but still not working (it is not NIL): -(IBAction) btnOk_Click {
 myOverlayChannelPicker = [[OverlayChannelPicker alloc] init];
 if(myOverlayChannelPicker != nil){
  [self.view addSubview:myOverlayChannelPicker];
 }
}

Comment: Stupid human error factor :) I didn't connect my new instance 'myOverlayChannelPicker' to variable in interface builder. Now it works :)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to make the call like this:

```
[self.view addSubview:myOverlayChannelPicker];
```

By the look of your posted code sample I have to assume that you have not been doing any objective-c development before. If that is the case you should probably start here [Introduction to The Objective-C Programming Language](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html) to get the basics covered.

Comment: That does not work also. Even when I type self addSu... there is no code complete for 'addSubview' :(

Comment: Still not working :( For objective C you guess :) I come from C# background but try to learn by doing :)

Comment: Learning by doing is the best way. Objective-c is a bit daunting a first and there are things that are different compared to C#, like calling methods, and manual memory management can be a pain in the beginning. But once you gotten started it is alot of fun. Another good place to start is http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/learn_objectivec/

Comment: Thanks :), but lets not go too far from question, I still need help to make this UIView to run...

Comment: If the code posted in my answer doesn't work one problem could that `myOverlayChannelPicker` is not initialized properly or at all. You should probably update your question with how you are creating `myOverlayPicker`.

Comment: I updated  answer. As I said when I manually drag it in interface builder it works fine. Problem is somewhere in runtime :(